# How to get a scanner value as a parameter value in java

Tags: java, parameters, queue, java.util.scanner

I want to give priority to my queue. So I assign a value to my inputs (1-4).
my code work well without Scanner. I input vehicle numbers as my input.

[image]

as in this image, I need to assign a scanner input to priority.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter vehicle number to continue:");

        Queue fq = new Queue(100);
        String input = null;


        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        while (in.hasNextLine() && (input = in.nextLine()).length() != 0) {
            fq.insert(new Vehicle(input)); //using this i only can get vehicle registration number for queue

            sb.append(in.nextInt((in.nextInt())));

        }
        fq.insert(new Vehicle("KR - 8428", 1)); // the number 1 after comma  in this line is my sorting value 
        fq.insert(new Vehicle("DP - 3432",4));// the number 4 after comma in this line is my sorting value 
        fq.insert(new Vehicle("300 - 4532", 3));// the number 3 after comma in this line is my sorting value 

        

    }

}
```

Comment: How is this not working? Can you describe the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question fully but if you are asking about how to input a vehicle number with a priority then just use a unique delimeter in the input and split it later like: input -> "KR - 8423;1"
`String[] data = input.split(';'); new Vehicle(data[0],data[1]);` will work just fine. You could then add pattern matcher and check for the delimeter present before splitting ..

Comment: Also, what is `sb.append(in.nextInt((in.nextInt())));` used for? you are expecting 2 numbers to be parsed as Integer in different radix? you are not prompting user to input these in the scanner so the console would be blind what to do

Comment: @LajosArpad by the print screen, it seems that Vehicle doesn't have a constructor accepting an instance of Scanner as parameter

Comment: @Stultuske `input` is a string not Scanner

Comment: @Mazmart indeed, I misread that in the original post. OK, so it seems it doesn't have a constructor accepting one String.

Comment: The supplied registration numbers are sorted based on what? The order of entry? I don't understand why a Queue is being used here.

Answer (score 0):

You have a constructor for `Vehicle` that expects a `String` and an `int` as parameters, but you are calling a constructor by passing a `String` only and you have no such constructor. A solution to your problem is to do the following:

```
fq.insert(new Vehicle(input, in.nextInt()));
```

I do not know what your `sb` is for, it seems to be unnecessary.